# Kubernetes API pod refuses connection

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I'm currently trying to setup a small cluster using CoreOS and Kubernetes. To get started, I'm following [this](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) tutorial. I have three CoreOS machines running on VirtualBox, using vagrant. I reached the [second step](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html) of the tutorial, but got stuck.

I seem to be able to startup the kubelet using `systemctl start kubelet`, but I can't seem to connect to the API server. Is seems as if it didn't start the API server, but tries to connect to it first.

When I enter `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/version`, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused` back.

Journalctl just shows me that kubelet is trying to connect to the API server and since the API server is not reachable, I can't use kubectl to see what is going on with the Pod. How should I tackle this problem?

**Edit:**

I executed the docker command manually and got the following back:

```
I1109 09:30:18.680796       1 plugins.go:69] No cloud provider specified.
I1109 09:30:18.826523       1 master.go:273] Node port range unspecified. Defaulting to 30000-32767.
E1109 09:30:18.847815       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/resourcequotas: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:18.848277       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Secret: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dkubernetes.io%2Fservice-account-token: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:18.848581       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ServiceAccount: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/serviceaccounts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:18.848766       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/limitranges: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:18.848943       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:18.849698       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
[restful] 2015/11/09 09:30:18 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://172.17.8.101:443/swaggerapi/
[restful] 2015/11/09 09:30:18 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://172.17.8.101:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
E1109 09:30:19.849251       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Secret: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dkubernetes.io%2Fservice-account-token: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:19.850278       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/resourcequotas: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:19.852294       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ServiceAccount: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/serviceaccounts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:19.852462       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/limitranges: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:19.852802       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:19.854201       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.852158       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Secret: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dkubernetes.io%2Fservice-account-token: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.852217       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/resourcequotas: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.853732       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ServiceAccount: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/serviceaccounts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.854456       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/limitranges: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.855127       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:20.855954       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused

... Repeated many times ...

E1109 09:30:35.882091       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:36.082552       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Secret: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dkubernetes.io%2Fservice-account-token: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:36.282562       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/resourcequotas: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1109 09:30:36.482611       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ServiceAccount: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/serviceaccounts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
F1109 09:30:36.664838       1 controller.go:80] Unable to perform initial IP allocation check: unable to refresh the service IP block: 501: All the given peers are not reachable (failed to propose on members [172.17.8.101 172.17.8.102 172.17.8.103] twice [last error: Get 172.17.8.103/v2/keys/registry/ranges/serviceips?quorum=false&recursive=false&sorted=false: unsupported protocol scheme ""]) [0]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave up on this setup for now. I think it has something todo with a misconfiguration in the ssl setup. For now I just use [this](https://coreos.com/blog/introducing-the-kubelet-in-coreos/) guide, in combination with the aformentioned tutorial, and stripped all the ssl related stuff from the configuration files. This gives me a working setup for now.

Comment: Url is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

You are going to setup the apiserver in the next step.  It is the thing that serves on 127.0.0.1:8080.  The kubelet should stop complaining once the apiserver is started.  The `curl` command you mentioned should work at that point too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I see the section "Set Up the kube-apiserver Pod" in part 3 of the tutorial. Strange though that they ask you to wait until the api server comes up, in part 2.I do not have the means to test this until next Monday. I'll let know if it worked out.

Comment: I seem to have missed something, as part 3 does not talk about setting up the API server. The problem persists.

Comment: It says to `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/pods/master/kubernetes.yaml` and `sudo cp kubernetes.yaml /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
 `.  The `kubernetes.yaml` contains the instructions for running kube-apiserver, and the `cp` command puts the files into a directory where the kubelet will automatically detect the file and read it and start apiserver.  After you do that step and wait a few moments, then `ps -ef` should show `kube-apiserver` running.  That will be serving on port 127.0.0.1:8080, and the kubelet will then talk to it.

Comment: @EricTune if you mean command `kubectl run kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gci.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1 --port=8080` that is done in the section before this issue is encountered. I didn't run into the issue in the OP but something similar